# Laravel-menus installation issue in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm having issue in installing the laravel menu package.

I'm trying to intall nwidart/laravel-menus package. My current project running
"php": "^8.0.2",
"laravel/framework": "^9.19",

> As I run

```
composer require nwidart/laravel-menus
```

It show error :- nwidart/laravel-menus 7.0 requires illuminate/support ^8.0

> Then If I try to install illuminate/support ^8.0 then it requires php 7.3 but I do not want to downgrade it.

Comment: well then only option for you will be fork the package and update it per your need.

Comment: ```"require": {
    "laravel/menus": "^3.0"
}``` Add in the composer.json file and give cmd "composer install"

Comment: Your package doesn't appear to have been updated for Laravel 9/10. It may no longer be actively maintained; the last commit was three years ago.